# How to use ReactJS in Asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

How to use ReactJS in Asp.net 4.0? Is it possible to use only with js files in asp.net? Should we install anything by using Nuget package manager? I am using Asp.net 4.0. Plz suggest steps for using Reactjs in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use ReactJS.NET. Otherwise you can just build and serve a js bundle with - for example - Webpack, just as you can with any server backend.